# Serial Communication - Sending Hex Data via Modbus

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus

I am new to using Modbus Communication, and I found some other related threads here but unfortunately, it was for other languages or using TCP rather than RTU connection for Modbus.

So I have this segment of C# code that I can use to send data:

```
  byte address = Convert.ToByte(txtSlaveID.Text);
  ushort start = Convert.ToUInt16(txtWriteRegister.Text);
  short[] value = new short[1];

  if(Int16.TryParse(txtWriteValue.Text, out short numberValue))
  {
     value[0] = numberValue; //This part works!
  }
  else
  {
     value = new short[3] { 0x52, 0x4E, 0x56 }; //This is where I am trying to send letters/ASCII
  }
                
 try
 {
     mb.SendFc16(address, start, (ushort)value.Length, value);
 }
     catch (Exception err)
 {
    WriteLog("Error in write function: " + err.Message);
 }

 WriteLog(mb.modbusStatus);
```

So when I want to send down a single value, this code works. It will take the short array and dow the following to build the packet:

```
  //Put write values into message prior to sending:
  for (int i = 0; i < registers; i++)
  {
    message[7 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i] >> 8);
    message[8 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i]);
  }
```

So as you can see I attempted to use the hex values in the array, and send them down to the registers.

[image: This is the image for the registers I am attempting to write to for the ASCII letters]

[image: This is the HEX codes I should use]

How can I modify the first sample of code to be able to send down HEX values, and write out characters into the register space in the first image?

Comment: Can't answer question.  Doesn't make any sense and sample code is missing definitions of variables.  RTU is only 8 bits so I'm not sure why you are shifting 8 bits and you are missing CRC calculation.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus

Comment: Jay - what is not working (are you getting a Modbus error or is the display just not doing what you expect?) - it would also help if you could identify the source of your Modbus code (is that from a library?). ASCII is 8 bits whereas the holding registers are 16 bits so it's quite possible the display expects two characters per register.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to write the character at the device's register.
You need not to store the hex values into the short array. Simply store the characters into array, before writing them into the register convert them into byte.

Note - Whatever data will be written into the devices register, should be in byte.